# Хранение анкеты в MySQL с возможностью дальнейшей фильтации

Tags: php, mysql

Есть Абстрактный пользователь. Для него существует анкета.Пример вопросов с вариантами ответов ниже.

1)Как зовут вашего попугая? (единичный выбор из нескольких значений - тип radio)

1. Кеша
2. Геша
3. Саша

2) Кого вы любите? (Абстрактная строка - string)

3) Когда вы кормите попугая?(множественный выбор из нескольких значений - checkbox)

1. Утром
2. Днем
3. Вечером
4. Всегда

Хранение полей анкеты - fields
id | Question | Answer
1 | Как зовут попугая? | serialize(array('Кеша','Геша','Саша'))
2 | Когда вы кормите попугая? |

Хранение выбора пользователя

```
id | user_id | field_id | value
1  | 1       | 1        | Кеша
1  | 1       | 2        | Даже не знаю чуваки.
```

При таком хранении мы отлично мы можем сделать фильтрацию по полям первого типа(что важно сразу в MySQL).

Но возникает проблема с фильтрацией поля третьего типа,так как там может быть выбрано несколько значений.

Прекрасным решением для чекбокса стало бы использование битовой маски,но проблема в том что мы имеем дело с полями не только этого типа. Да и собрать нормально биты того что мы хотим будет проблематично.

Кто может подтолкнуть к решению? Или подать дельную идею или ссылочку?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что данные у вас всегда неструктурированные? Т.е. вы не знаете состав полей, которые будут поступать в будущем? А использовать нечто вроде MongoDB нет возможности? Я боюсь в этом случае нет удобного способа, только денормализовать третье значение и хранить его классически.

Comment: @cheops, с чекбоксом - да,неизвестно какие поля могут быть выбраны.может быть выбран как один пункт,так и все. То есть вы предлагаете вычленить и таблицы поле value и хранить её в отдельной таблице вместе с id записи для профиля? К сожалению в распоряжении есть только реляцион(

Comment: Хранить коллекцией удобно в лишь в какой-то документ-ориентированной базе данных, в MySQL удобно работать будет лишь после нормализации. Хороших типов данных, вроде JSON, как в постгресе тут нет и судя по всему уже не появится.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ответы хранить в строковом поле. По номерам ваших типов:

1. № пункта
2. буквально введённая строка
3. все выбранные №№ через запятую в порядке возрастания

Поиск по 1 и 2 типу очевиден — простое сравнение строк. Поиск по 3-му типу:

- на полное совпадение — как простое сравнение строк,
- на попадание отдельного пункта — через [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).